# Concrete table inheritance with TypeORM - compilation fails with abstract keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, typeorm

i was hoping someone could help me with class inheritance with regards to TypeORM. right now i’m trying to achieve concrete table inheritance (which i found here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entity-inheritance.md#concrete-table-inheritance), but i’m seeing this:

```
{ SyntaxError: .../src/entities/User.js: Unexpected
 token (3:16)

  1 | import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';
  2 |
> 3 | export abstract class User {
    |                 ^
  4 |   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  5 |   id = undefined;
```

which i’m guessing is because my babel config is wrong or incomplete. if it helps i followed roughly what i found here: https://github.com/typeorm/babel-example.

the command that’s producing the error is `$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm schema:drop` (edited)

Comment: Please edit your title to ask a specific question rather than listing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example repository you used is for JavaScript code, not TypeScript.  If you want to use it with TypeScript code, you could try enabling the `transform-typescript` plugin in `.babelrc`, though you may be better off using one of the TypeScript examples from [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/README.md#samples).  Alternatively, just delete the `abstract`.  (`abstract` is a TypeScript-only feature.)

Comment: this turned out to be noise. it was an oversight on my part. i tried earlier making the file a `.ts` file and configuring babel setup to handle it as such (no idea what i'm doing). i also tried removing the `abstract` keyword. when you mentioned it again i went back and realized that the problem was the way i was exporting. `export class User {};` was the issue as i was trying to import it elsewhere expecting a default export. `class User {}; export default User;` fixed the issue. as an aside, TypeORM is acting differently depending on whether you import using a default or by destructuring